# How to manually install an artifact in Maven 2?

Tags: maven-2, installation

I've encountered some errors when I tried to install an artifact manually with Maven 2. I wanted to install a jar from a local directory with the command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jta-1.0.1B.jar
```

But Maven gave a build error which reads like:

```
Invalid task '.01B.jar': you must
specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a
goal in the format plugin:goal or
pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
```

Is there a mistake with my command?

Comment: What is the status of this? Is you question resolved?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You need to indicate the groupId, the artifactId and the version for your artifact:

```
mvn install:install-file \
  -DgroupId=javax.transaction \
  -DartifactId=jta \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -Dversion=1.0.1B \
  -Dfile=jta-1.0.1B.jar \
  -DgeneratePom=true
```

Comment: -Dpackaging=jar or similar is missing

Comment: @kaboom No! By default, the packaging is jar, so you don't need to specify this in thé command...

Comment: does not work for me too:  Missing group, artifact, version, or packaging information

Comment: @romaintaz kaboom is correct; you need -Dpackaging=jar (or whatever the type is) otherwise you will get an error about "'packaging' is missing."

Comment: It seems that the packaging parameter is needed except if you provide a pom file. In the latter case, the type of package is taken from the pom.

Comment: +1 for `-DgeneratePom=true`.  Otherwise you get warnings when using the artifact that the pom is missing.

Comment: If using PowerShell, make sure you use quote likewise `"-DgroupId=javax.transaction"`

Answer (score 39):

According to maven's [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html), the command is:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

You need indeed the packaging option. This answers the original question.

Now, in your context, you are fighting with a jar provided by Sun. You should read the [Coping with Sun JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html) page too. There, you'll learn how to help maven to provide you better information about Sun jars location and how to add Java.net [Maven 2 repository](https://maven2-repository.dev.java.net/) which **contains** `jta-1.0.1B.jar`. Add this in your <strike>`settings.xml` (not portable) or</strike> `pom.xml` (portable):

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Answer (score 16):

I had to add packaging, so:

```
mvn install:install-file \
  -DgroupId=javax.transaction \
  -DartifactId=jta \
  -Dversion=1.0.1B \
  -Dfile=jta-1.0.1B.jar \
  -DgeneratePom=true \
  -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: I had lots of issues installing a jar file manually, and it kept failing until I typed it this way exactly. Now it works!

Answer (score 8):

Answer is to escape the dash!

http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg83991.html

Comment: Damm me. that was it. all the -D parameters must be enclosed in `.

Answer (score 4):

If you ever get similar errors when using Windows PowerShell, you should try Windows' simple command-line. I didn't find out what caused this, but PowerShell seems to interpret some of Maven's parameters.

Comment: Look at S. Bollweber answer above. And at least TakeCommand expresses the same bahaviour.

Comment: No reason to downvote my answer – S. Bollweber answered a few months after myself.

Answer (score 2):

All the posted answers rightfully discuss this from a strictly maven perspective.  My issues was in doing this install for maven using Netbeans as my primary IDE.  I found the below article helpful.

Credit to the following netbeans forum article:  http://forums.netbeans.org/topic22907.html

1. In Maven project open "Add dependency" dialog
2. Make up some groupId, artifactId and version and fill them, OK.
3. Dependency will be added to the pom.xml and will appear under
   "Libraries" node of maven project
4. Right-click Lib node and "manually install artifact", fill the path
    to the jar.  Jar should be installed to local Maven repo with 
    coordinates entered in step 2)