# Use windows drive letters in maven install:install-file

Tags: maven, maven-3, drive-letter

When I try to install a custom jar with the following maven command then it will fail misirably:

```
mvn -X install:install-file -Dfile=D:\Work\...
```

Howerver the following does work:

```
mvn -X install:install-file -Dfile=\Work\...
```

You might now ask: So where is the problem? Well, I want to import from a script file and there I have the path with drive letter and all other trimmings.

So how would I go about this?

PS: The error message is:

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'D'
>   in the current project and in the> plugin groups
>   [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.code
>   haus.mojo] available from the
>   repositories [local (D:\Repository),
>   central
>   (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] ->
>   [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException:
>   No plugin found for prefix 'D' in the
>   current project and in the plugin
>   groups [org.apache.maven.plugins,
>   org.codehaus.mojo] available from the
>   repositories

PPS: No spell checker in the companies bloody IE :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I opted for:

```
PUSHD %[PROJECT_HOME]
    CALL mvn    ^
     install:install-file  ^
     `-Dfile=lib/ojdbc14.jar` ^
     `-DgroupId=com.oracle`  ^
     `-DartifactId=ojdbc14`  ^
     `-Dversion=9.0.2.0.0`  ^
     `-Dpackaging=jar`
POPD
```

I used:

- PUSHD so I can use relative path names .
- CALL so the script won't prematurly end.
- forward slashes instead of backslashes.
- all -D parameters need to be backticked under Windows.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I got a very similar error except my was prefix 'C'...

After reading this thread, I added single quotation mark to my jar file name as -`Dfile=‘C:\work\perforce\trunk\Lib\ftp4j\ftp4j-1.7.2.jar’` and you need to make sure there is no space between the `=` and the `'`.

Adding the single quotes fixed it and I was able to have `"BUILD SUCCESS"` as my output after the install.

But guess what I see in my repository folder? The `ftp4j-1.7.2.jar.lastUpdated`, `ftp4j-1.7.2.pom`, `ftp4j-1.7.2.pom.lastUpdated` files were all created in the folder by the installation, but the actual `ftp4j-1.7.2.jar` was NOT/failed to copy over...So at this point, I just manually copy the `ftp4j-1.7.2.jar` over myself to the repository and that seems to finally work.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using PowerShell, but somehow, it was resolved when I used Command Prompt...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try by using a valid Java path string ?

- replacing '\' with '/'
- or doubling each '\'

Comment: No problem on the command line. But rather difficult to archive in script file. Besides I also noticed a 2nd problem which is anwered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442230/how-to-manually-install-an-artifact-in-maven-2 - check for the answere of S. Bollweber. I guess I need to refactor my scripts to use relativ path names.

Comment: Seen, but I just took a look at my own script and I noticed I do 'call mvn ...' instead of simply 'mvn ...' don't know if this help you (and I use only relative path)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me - of course I need to use CALL as well else the script will end after the first install (there is only one right now - but this will change).

Answer (score 0):

Example for ojdbc6.jar install (on Windows).

Download ojdbc drivers from [Oracle](http://%20https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html). Next in "Command Shell" issue command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="C:\Users\yourusername\Downloads\ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar" -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar
```