# Where to find the public maven repository for Tomcat-JDBC Pool?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, connection-pooling

i am trying to use the tomcat jdbc-pool in my application but it seems that i cannot find a repository that provides this dependency. Any clue in which repository i can find the latest release that can be used in a Maven build?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the correct dependency information for the Tomcat JDBC Pool.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are deploying to Tomcat the required JARs are bundled with the Tomcat servlet container, you don't have to (and *shouldn't*) include them in your WAR file.

Instead you should [define the JDBC connection pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) in Tomcat itself and then simply reference it in your application using JNDI.

Comment: I checked and could be mistaken offcourse, but the jdbc-pool is not in the standard distro. The dbcp is there but not the jdbc-pool. I placed it in /lib dir and then it seems to work.

Comment: It's not good practice to dump dependencies in your WEB-INF classes or lib folder. Rather use the correct dependency (below) or manually add a "custom artifact" to your local maven repository. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442230/how-to-manually-install-an-artifact-in-maven-2