# Maven build throwing error could not resolve dependencies

Tags: java, maven, backbone.js, jboss

So i'm a front end developer that has no prior java experience and currently working on a project that uses backbone on the front end but java on the back and in order to get started on this project they supplied me with a build in which i was instructed to run 'mvn -Psystem-setup' ..

All seems to be going how it should until it throws an error saying ..

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ee-api-validation: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.spartasystems.eeee api-validation:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.jboss.solder:solder-impl:jar:3.2.0.Final: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.solder:solder-impl:jar:3.2.0.Final: 
Failure to find org.jboss.seam:seam-bom:pom:3.1.0.Final in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I am completely lost and do not know what to do or how to fix this and have tried searching the internet for answers but everything i find and then try does not work. Can somebody please help me?

If you need me to post more stuff let me know and i will.

thank you!

HERE IS THE DEPENDENCY SECTION OF POM.XML FILE...

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha-4</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.solder</groupId>
            <artifactId>solder-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${version.javassist}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.weld}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketlink-core</artifactId>
            <version>${picketlink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketlink.distribution</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketlink-jbas7</artifactId>
            <version>${picketlink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-weld-se-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-annotations-ejb3</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossws-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ws.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbossws-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.picketlink</groupId>
            <artifactId>picketlink-consolidated-social</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.2012sep25</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: can you post the dependencies section of the pom.xml for your project?

Comment: it seems the last line is issue. Force update the Maven. Right click project, maven, update and click on force update

Comment: @ZachOfAllTrades just posted it above..

Comment: Are you using the same development environment that the java developers are? There are a whole bunch of items specified with scope "provided" -- if you don't have a server runtime setup that matches whatever the java developers were using, then you will not be able to run this project.

Comment: @ZachOfAllTrades i'm connected to their VPN while i'm running these commands... i'm assuming thats what you mean? I'm not having any issues as far as getting connected to the vpn network and this is the exact file that they sent me i havent touched or changed a thing

Comment: not what I meant - I was referring to the development IDE that you are using. There are dependencies marked as "provided" which implies that they are part of a server runtime. But if you don't have the corresponding server runtime (perhaps because you are not a part of the same Java development team), then there are more pieces that need to be in place before you can import the Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute `mvn clean install` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: tried it and getting same error :( ..i'm posting the pom.xml file now

Answer (score 1):

This could be a network problem resulting into incorrect resolution or your local proxy glitches.

Try

```
mvn -Psystem-setup clean install -U
```

And if doesn't help, remove artifacts manually from a folder `$HOME/.m2/repository/org.jboss`, after this

```
mvn -Psystem-setup clean install
```

And if this doesn't help, you may try downloading and installing  the jar manually: [How to manually install an artifact in Maven 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442230/how-to-manually-install-an-artifact-in-maven-2)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a network issue ... Make sure that you are not behind any firewall

Answer (score 0):

You can try erase part of your .m2 library in your /home//.m2 or in window your user directory.

So maven can download again the jars