# Cant able to create springboot project in STS 4

Tags: spring

I have dowloaded the STS 4 above version trying to create my STS project from spring io and downloaded Using maven trying to import at that time getting

> **Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.example</groupId>
 <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>demo</name>
 <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.2.4.RELEASE
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed
>   out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM**

**

Am not sure what is the problem Maven installed properly in my machine also

My pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Post your complete pom file. The definition of parent is not visible now

Comment: yes added the complete pom file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735976/non-resolvable-parent-pom

Comment: It seems to be sts compatibility issue, please create the same application through sts directly.

Comment: This is an IDE issue. I had the same issue and i resolved it by deleting the content of the pom file and saving it blank. Then again populating the content and saving it again. This should fix it. You might also have to `Project --> Clean` a couple of times.

Comment: after clean getting [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

Comment: Niraj Jha ---am getting  SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out error through direct sts creation

Comment: I don't think you are on public network probably under private or some firewall, restricting maven to connect central repository. You should try through browser is the repository accessible? If not check with network/IT team.