# How to get Oracle 6 jar from Maven to my local repository

Tags: java, ojdbc

How to add Oracle to my dependencies from Maven.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle JDBC Driver jars are not hosted on Maven Central due to license restrictions. You can find some jars in Maven Central but it's not guaranteed that they will work with your database version.

Instead You should download the right driver from the Oracle website (e.g. [Oracle Database 12.1.0.1 JDBC Driver & UCP Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html)) and host it yourself (either in your local repo or with `<system>scope</system>` dependency). Take a look at [this answer which shows how to install the jar into local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/442243/1602555).

Answer (score 0):

Add the Oracle 6 jar in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```